# Bitmap issue specific to 4.2.2 (and possibly right to left notated languages)?

Tags: android, bitmap, crashlytics

I am using https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3143 and in my Crashlytics I do receive plenty of strange crash reports impacting **only Android 4.2.2** - the issue I face is:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits
>   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Bitmap.java)
>   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:782)
>   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:759)
>   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:726) ...

My app is available for 4.1+ and there are no reports from other OS versions. Two questions

1) Are you aware of a Bitmap.java issue impacting only 4.2.2? (I have 50+ reports, all from 4.2.2 while its below 15% of all my app users).

2) Is there some easy way to seek for known, unresolved issues that impact a specific Android version?

PS. I am unable to trace this right now (will possibly do in the future) but from Crash reports in Google Console I am guessing its impacting only Arabic countries. (Right to Left + Android 4.2.2 as a cause?)

thanks in advance.

Comment: after some debugging it seems that onMeasure is not called on RTL language in 4.2.2 same as in other cases. The bitmap issue was a side effect of this. Hope this will help others.